# C++ what happen if I convert pointer type?

Tags: c++

When we allocate a piece of memory, such as:

```
double* ptr = new double[10];
```

It gives me a pointer that points to the 1st location of 10 continuous memory location of double

Now if I do:

```
unsigned char* ptr2 = (unsigned char*)ptr;
```

does it create another unsigned char pointer that points to the 1st location of ptr, then translate the array into unsigned char (which the size is nolonger 10)?

If not, how to do so?

Comment: So physically what happen in the memory...

Comment: @LiangzeLu casting pointer to char usually does nothing to memory

Comment: @LiangzeLu nothing changed in the array of 10 `doubles`.  The code can now use it as if it's an array of `char`.  Note however that aliasing memory like this has some very strict rules if you want to avoid Undefined Behaviour. See [Type aliasing in here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: to find out answer I suggest you to start with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: Try adding (for example) `*ptr2 = 42;` to your code.  _Now_ you're changing the first byte of that array of `double`s.  So I think the answer to your question is 'yes', but the language barrier isn't helping (which is not your fault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-style cast of a pointer type `(type *)ptr` does nothing at all to the bit pattern. It simply tells the compiler to consider the pointer to be of the new type. Something that is rather dangerous as in most cases using the result is just UB.

Now char is a special case because it is used to access the raw memory underlying any data. So you can cast any pointer (not function or member pointers) to a char pointer and use it to access the bit pattern of the data. You can also cast a char pointer back to the original type safely. Pretty much everything else quickly becomes UB.

Look at the C++ style casts for better and safer methods: const_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast, .